# How to bring a view to front when doing animation?

Tags: android

Right now I am implementing a feature where I need to animate any ImageView in the app to full screen when it is clicked. And when back it hit, a reverse animation will be applied to restored the ImageView to original position. The ImageView can be anywhere in the view tree. To simplify the description, consider this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the corresponding kotlin file:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<View>(R.id.image2).setOnClickListener {
            it.animate().scaleX(5.0f).scaleY(5.0f).setDuration(5000L).start()
        }

        findViewById<View>(R.id.image3).setOnClickListener {
            it.animate().scaleX(5.0f).scaleY(5.0f).setDuration(5000L).start()
        }
    }
}
```

Here when we click image2 or image3 we want it to scale up. However the result is not what we want. For image2 it will be covered by image3 after scaling up. For image3 it will simply be clipped:

[image2 covered by image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQMhi.png)

[image3 clipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDisO.png)

What's the right way to temporarily bring the ImageView to front?

Comment: Have you try the `View's bringToFront()` ?

Comment: @Longalei That won't work. For example calling bringToFront() on the second view will change it to the third position. bringToFront() works by changing the order of it's children.

Answer (score 4):

Try this it would help you

```
class BottomNavigationExample : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_navigation_example)

    findViewById<View>(R.id.image2).setOnClickListener {
        it.animate().scaleX(5.0f).scaleY(5.0f).setDuration(5000L).start()
        setElevation(it)
    }

    findViewById<View>(R.id.image3).setOnClickListener {
        it.animate().scaleX(5.0f).scaleY(5.0f).setDuration(5000L).start()
        setElevation(it)
    }

}

fun setElevation(view: View) {
    ViewCompat.setElevation(image1, 0f);    
    ViewCompat.setElevation(image2, 0f);
    ViewCompat.setElevation(image3, 0f);
    ViewCompat.setElevation(view, 5f);

}
```

}

Comment: great solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this..

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {


private var currentAnimator: Animator? = null
private var shortAnimationDuration: Int = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val thumbView: View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1)
    val thumbView2: View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_2)

    thumbView.setOnClickListener { zoomImageFromThumb(thumb_button_1, R.drawable.image1) }
    thumbView2.setOnClickListener { zoomImageFromThumb(thumb_button_2, R.drawable.girls2) }


    shortAnimationDuration = resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime)

}

private fun zoomImageFromThumb(thumbView: View, imageResId: Int) {
    currentAnimator?.cancel()

    val expandedImageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.expanded_image)
    expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId)

    val startBoundsInt = Rect()
    val finalBoundsInt = Rect()
    val globalOffset = Point()

    thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBoundsInt)
    findViewById<View>(R.id.container)
        .getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBoundsInt, globalOffset)
    startBoundsInt.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y)
    finalBoundsInt.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y)

    val startBounds = RectF(startBoundsInt)
    val finalBounds = RectF(finalBoundsInt)

    val startScale: Float
    if ((finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height() > startBounds.width() / startBounds.height())) {
        // Extend start bounds horizontally
        startScale = startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height()
        val startWidth: Float = startScale * finalBounds.width()
        val deltaWidth: Float = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2
        startBounds.left -= deltaWidth.toInt()
        startBounds.right += deltaWidth.toInt()
    } else {
        // Extend start bounds vertically
        startScale = startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width()
        val startHeight: Float = startScale * finalBounds.height()
        val deltaHeight: Float = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2f
        startBounds.top -= deltaHeight.toInt()
        startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight.toInt()
    }

    thumbView.alpha = 0f
    expandedImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    expandedImageView.pivotX = 0f
    expandedImageView.pivotY = 0f

    currentAnimator = AnimatorSet().apply {
        play(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                expandedImageView,
                View.X,
                startBounds.left,
                finalBounds.left
            )
        ).apply {
            with(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    expandedImageView,
                    View.Y,
                    startBounds.top,
                    finalBounds.top
                )
            )
            with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScale, 1f))
            with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f))
        }
        duration = shortAnimationDuration.toLong()
        interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
        addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                currentAnimator = null
            }

            override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {
                currentAnimator = null
            }
        })
        start()
    }

    expandedImageView.setOnClickListener {
        currentAnimator?.cancel()


        currentAnimator = AnimatorSet().apply {
            play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left)).apply {
                with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top))
                with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScale))
                with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScale))
            }
            duration = shortAnimationDuration.toLong()
            interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
            addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                    thumbView.alpha = 1f
                    expandedImageView.visibility = View.GONE
                    currentAnimator = null
                }

                override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {
                    thumbView.alpha = 1f
                    expandedImageView.visibility = View.GONE
                    currentAnimator = null
                }
            })
            start()
        }
    }
}
```

}

layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/thumb_button_2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/girls2" />


</LinearLayout>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```